# How can you filter between two lists using a function in Python?

Tags: python, string, function, filter

I am attempting to get Python to filter values between two lists. It is pasting the values of the original list and ignoring the instructions. Thanks in advance for your input.

```
string_val = ['Tom','Kyle','Carl','Tom','Mike','Austin']
delval = ['Tom','Kyle']


def filter_list(string_val, delval):
    new_string =[]
    for v in string_val:
        if (string_val) != (delval):
            new_string.append(v)
    return new_string

result = filter_list(string_val, delval)
print(result)
```

Comment: what are you trying to do with `(string_val) != (delval)` statement?

Comment: Did you mean `not in` instead of `!=`? Right now, you're comparing each string in `string_val` to the _entire list_ `['Tom' 'Kyle']`, not to each individual element in that list/

Comment: What are you trying to do? Like do you want to create a new list with elements in string_val that are not in string_val?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're comparing wrong value, you should compare each value instead of entire delval.

```
def filter_list(string_val, delval):
    new_string =[]
    for v in string_val:
        found = False
        if v not in delval:
            new_string.append(v)
    return new_string

result = filter_list(string_val, delval)
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you are iterating through `string_val` which has names. You want to check if each name is in `delval`. Do this using `in`
I think your looking for something like this (list comprehension)

```
string_val = ['Tom','Kyle','Carl','Tom','Mike','Austin']
delval = ['Tom','Kyle']
def filterList(string_val,delval):
    return [names for names in string_val if names not in delval]
print(filterList(string_val,delval))
```

**output**

```
['Carl', 'Mike', 'Austin']
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the Python one-liner code to find the disjoint elements.

```
def filter_list(string_val, delval):
    return list(set(string_val) - set(delval))
```

Output

```
['Austin', 'Mike', 'Carl']
```